# How to avoid error message in mini-buffer (helm-mode, emacs24.4)

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I installed helm package by using pacage-install.

According to [this page](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki),
I added the following code in init.el.

**.emacs.d/init.el**

```
(when (require 'helm-config)                                                                            
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c h") 'helm-mini)                                                             
  (helm-mode 1))
```

when I press "M-x" key and entered any letter, I get following error message in mini-buffer.

**message in mini-buffer**

```
Error running timer `helm-mp-highlight-match-internal': (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
```

The functionality of helm partially works. But this is inconvenient for me. Does anyone know workaround for the problem?

**conditions**

OS: Ubuntu 14.10

emacs version: 24.4.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.12.2)

(**when I use emacs 24.3, this problem doesn't occur.**)

helm version: helm-20141106.257

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, it may very well be that this error in `helm-mp-highlight-match-internal` happened also in 24.3: one of the difference in 24.4 is that errors in timers are not silently ignored any more but are instead reported as messages in the minibuffer.

You should probably report this problem to Thierry Volpiatto (maintainer/author of Helm).

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I will report it to the autour of Helm.